# How to reformat and modify a date string according to DIN standard: 5008:2020-03?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### How can I reformat and modify a date string?

---

My code:

```
details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
for detail in details:
    released = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[1]/span/text()').get()
    item['released'] = released
    yield item
```

My output:

> Released 2021, September 24

---

**Desired output:**

> 24. September, 2021

**and:**

> 24.09.2021

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `scrapy`, as this is a simple string parsing problem.

For example, you might want to try this, provided that `released` is a string value like `Released 2021, September 24`:

```py
import datetime

released = "Released 2021, September 24".replace("Released ", "")
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(released, '%Y, %B %d').strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
```

Output:

```
24.09.2021
```

To get the longer output:

```py
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(released, '%Y, %B %d').strftime("%d. %B, %Y"))
```

Output:

```
24. September, 2021
```

EDIT:

In order to apply it in your code, try this:

```py
details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
for detail in details:
    released = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[1]/span/text()').get()
    item['released'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(released.replace("Released ", ""), '%Y, %B %d').strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    yield item
```

Comment: Edited accordingly. Thanks @baduker

Comment: I have not managed to implement the solution in my code. Could you describe this using my example with the item?

Comment: What's the value of `released = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[1]/span/text()').get()`? Is this text, as the XPath suggests?

Comment: Yes, the value is text.

Comment: See the updated answer, @Alexander.